# CSS background img

Tags: html, css

У меня есть картинка размером 2000х1333 и мне нужно поставить ее на бг, чтоб полностью по блоку была.
Когда я пытаюсь, то получается что-то типа того:
(красный бордер - размер блока)
[image: фэйл]

CSS:

```
#header {
 background: #fff url('../img/bg1.png') center no-repeat;
 background-size: auto;
 max-width: 1920px;
 height: 1080px;
 border-top: 11px solid #204055;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: `background-size: cover | contain | 100%;`

Comment: contain:
Масштабирует изображение с сохранением пропорций таким образом, чтобы картинка целиком поместилась внутрь блока.
Немного не то, что нужно.

Comment: ок, тогда как мне можно сделать, чтоб блоку задавался размер картинки?

Comment: если Вам нужно, чтобы картинка не сжималась или растягивалась по блоку теряя внешний вид - поставьте ширину и высоту блока как у картинки, но это тупиковый ход, задайте размер блока как он есть и вместите картинку по блоку как я сказал. Или не используйте background, а задайте картинке position:absolute, а блоку - position:relative. (Плюс настройки картинки конечно: ширина: 100%; топ:0, лефт:0 и т.д.).

Comment: я использовал картинку (не бг) и теперь она не скейлится, не адаптивной получается ;C

Answer (score 1):

Используйте:

```
background-size:100%;
```

или

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Как предложили

```
background-size: cover;
```

Можете дополнить, также

```
background-position: center;
```